# How to make the search result show up in different rows and structure under 1 header

Tags: html, css, jsp

So I have this JSP search function as you can see below:

```
<%
String value=request.getParameter("search");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://instance****.db.xeround.com:*****/mydb", "*****", "*******");
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT menu.name, menu.info, menu.price, restaurants.name from menu,"
        + " restaurants where restaurants_restaurantID=RestaurantID AND (menu.name like '%"
        + value
        + "%' "
        + "or menu.info like '%"
        + value
        + "%' or menu.category like '%"
        + value
        + "%' "
        + "or menu.kitchen like '%"
        + value
        + "%' or quick_choose like '%" + value + "%')");

while (rs.next()){ 
    %>
<tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" value="<%=rs.getString("name")%>" > </td></tr>
<tr><td>Info:</td><td><input type="text" value="<%=rs.getString("info")%>" > </td></tr>
<tr><td>Price:</td><td><input type="text" value="<%=rs.getInt("price")%>" > </td></tr>
      <%
}
%>
```

This is working and pulling the info I need from the database, but what I want to do right now is to somehow make the results line up correctly as in that each result line will display only the name/dish description/price for one food. also I want it to work With a top header that looks like this: [Here](http://translate.google.se/translate?sl=sv&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=sv&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http://www.lindholmen.se/sv/dagens-lunch)

Where the results displays under the header Restaurant, Dish, Type, Price. So that they displays correctly under those titles.

And then divide each line with a line. Such as in facebook when you go and search something, the results will be shown and divided by a thin line.

Same as the link above and Shown here:
[image: the line]

Summary for those who don't wanna read too much: I basically want my search results to be like this site:[Here](http://translate.google.se/translate?sl=sv&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=sv&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http://www.lindholmen.se/sv/dagens-lunch), under a header devided into different colums and have a line that separates each search result.

Do any of you know any possible solution for this in HTML? Or can give me any advice on how to preceed? I've tried a few alternatives but I just can't figure it out. Would really appraciate any help or guidance. Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Create an `<a>` tag for each result with the `href` attribute pointing at whatever the link is supposed to be. In your case I'm *assuming*, but you don't say, that you'd want to pass a restaurant ID to a servlet (because you shouldn't be writing Java in a JSP).

Comment: Oh sorry I wrote the wrong titles. You can check the re-edited summary.

Comment: I still don't understand the question. If you want separate "sections" then add the HTML for separate sections.

Comment: Uhm, the reason I added my current search function was to show how it prints out the results right now as you can see at the end of the code. I showed a site [link](http://translate.google.se/translate?sl=sv&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=sv&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lindholmen.se%2Fsv%2Fdagens-lunch)that has the search results shown in the way I want it to be. So thats why I'm asking if anyone knows how to make a header like that, that makes the search results display under it. Also a line that divides each search result.

Comment: So you're asking how to do CSS?

Comment: both HTML and CSS I think.

Comment: why don't you just look at the HTML of the sites you want to look like and copy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necessary to you **html**:

```
<table>
  <tr class="head">
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td>Info:</td>
    <td>Price:</td>
  </tr>    
<%
 while (rs.next()){ 
%>
  <tr class="content">
    <td class="name"><%=rs.getString("name")%></td>
    <td class="info"><%=rs.getString("info")%></td>
    <td class="price"><%=rs.getInt("price")%></td>
  </tr>
<%
 }
%>
</table>
```

and approximate **css**:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.head td {
    text-align: center;
}
.content td {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
}
.info {
    background-color: #F1F4F6;
}
```

But first, scriptlets is very poor practice. Secondly, getting of database connection in JSP is shot in the head. 
Your JSP page should be responsible only for view. Replace your code into separate Java classes. Otherwise, when your code will bloat your project will be unreadable and bad maintainable.

Using [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html) you can  get easily the same view:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${requestScope.items}">
   <div id="item_title" class="item_title">
      <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}${item.url}">
        <c:out value="${item.title}" />
      </a>
   </div>
   <div id="item_content" class="item_content">
      <c:out value"${item.content}" />
   </div>
<c:forEach>
```

or

```
   <div id="item_title" class="item_title">
      <form name="openItem" action="handlerurl" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="${item.id}" />
        <c:out value="${item.title}" />
        <input type="submit" value="read more" />
      </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: I know its very bad, I just started studie Java like a month ago, so I'm really not good at it. I can see how poor it must look to you guys that programmed for quite some time. But I'll try to remember this. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Thank you so much good sir, I was asleep so I couldnt check it until now, I'll remember what your advice! Thanks again!